# ng-valid class on default select control option

Tags: angular

Hi I`m using Angular 6 reactive form, and I`m using floating label HTML, where label goes up only when field is ng valid.

//My Control

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="floating-label">
      <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="systemId" [disabled]="loginSysId!=='Admin'" #txtSysId disabled>
        <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let val of systemId" [ngValue]="val">{{val}}</option>
      </select>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <label>System Id</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If I`m selecting the options formed from systemId variable ng-valid is applied to control, but when I`m selecting --select-- it remains same ng-invalid.. Kindly help I`m new to angular

Comment: When you select '--Select--'. we are emitting value as null. That means model doesn't have value. You can pass 0/-1 to make it ng-valid.

Comment: I can`t make the value 0 or 1, it is sent to an api, any other options

Comment: Try with empty(with space) ' '